# How could a Jersey client handle a huge payload without causing a memory issue?

Tags: java, jackson, out-of-memory, streaming, heap-memory

I have to write a Jersey client which should handle a huge payload (>1GB) but the problem is if I use the java object model then I am getting a memory error. I am considering using Jackson streaming API but I am confused that it will still get buffered in memory and occupy more than 1 GB space. Can someone explain how streaming works on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jackson Streaming API is identical for both the server and client side. It can be very efficient but it is substantially more work than the Databind API since you have to code a bunch of that work yourself. (see [Jackson Performance](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation:-Jackson-Performance))

Functionally, you want to leave the input in the stream and parse (and process) it piece by piece. In cases where you know the structure or it happens to be an array you can theoretically process each object in the array one-by-one to avoid having to read the entire array before processing.

```
JsonFactory factory = ObjectMapper.getJsonFactory();

try(JsonParser parser = factory.createJsonParser(inputStream)) {

    while(parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        // process tokens, etc. here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Baldy.